# Custom font size for itemize

Tags: lists, itemize, fontsize

I am making a checklist to print, where users can check their answers on a printed paper.
For this I am using `itemize` and `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\Box}`, `\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\Box}` etc..., which works fine.

What I now want is to make items, sub-items and sub-sub-items different sized, so that the higher the hierarchy, the bigger font.
Since I have a lot of things to check, I don't want to specify each line in the latex document, but was hoping to use a `\renewcommand{\itemi}{something}` or something like that.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define your own `itemize` environment which uses the normal one but changes the font size first. The `relsize` package gives you the handy `\smaller` and `\larger` macros.

This would make every level one font size step smaller.

```
\usepackage{relsize}

\newenvironment{xitemize}{%
    \smaller
    \itemize
}{%
    \enditemize
}
```

This would make the first level smaller then the text. If this is not wanted change `\smaller` to `\ifnum\csname @itemdepth\endcsname=0\else\smaller\fi`.

If you want to keep the `itemize` name in your documents, use:

```
\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    \smaller
    \olditemize
}{%
    \endolditemize
}
```

You could define your own set of e.g. `\fontitemi`, `\fontitemii`, ... macros:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xitemize}{%
    \@nameuse{fontitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}
    \itemize
}{%
    \enditemize
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\fontitem}{\Huge}
\newcommand{\fontitemi}{\Large}
\newcommand{\fontitemii}{\large}
\newcommand{\fontitemiii}{\normalsize}
\newcommand{\fontitemiv}{\small}
```